# output only certain results in a log file from batch file

Tags: windows, logging, batch-file

relatively new to batch files so please help me out;). What I'm trying to do is create a customized log file. Simple example:

```
ipconfig >> ip.log
```

this will display all the TCP/IP related info.

Let's say I only need the user to see the IP and Default Gateway, so the result in the output ip.log should look like this:

```
IPv4 Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Default Gateway: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Generally you would use a [filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28software%29) for that purpose. You want to filter on certain strings, so `findstr` command is natural choice:

```
ipconfig | findstr /c:"IPv4 Address" /c:"Default Gateway" >>ip.log
```